# PHP - mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM XXXX";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$noOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

How to check if `$result` is empty before getting the result of `mysql_num_rows`?

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_` extensions have been deprecated - http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `$result` with a ternary operator and set `$noOfRows` to `0` if it is `false`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM XXXX";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$noOfRows = (false===$result)? 0 : mysql_num_rows($result);
```